Why should I use portTICK_PERIOD_MS instead of pdMS_TO_TICKS?
I can retrieve the number of ticks needed to reach, say, 500 ms using either:
const TickType_t xDelay = 500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS

or:
const TickType_t xDelay = pdMS_TO_TICKS(500);

where:
#define portTICK_PERIOD_MS              ( ( TickType_t ) 1000 / configTICK_RATE_HZ )

#define pdMS_TO_TICKS( xTimeInMs )    ( ( TickType_t ) ( ( ( TickType_t ) ( xTimeInMs ) * ( TickType_t ) configTICK_RATE_HZ ) / ( TickType_t ) 1000U ) )

To me, both #define seem to do the same thing. Is there any difference about performance or other stuff?

portTICK_PERIOD_MS is the number of ticks per millisecond.  pdMS_TO_TICKS converts milliseconds to ticks.

@FiddlingBits exactly, but dividing for portTICK_PERIOD_MS like in the first example does not converts to ticks as well?

Sorry, I missed that part.  To be the same, const TickType_t xDelay = 500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS should be const TickType_t xDelay = 500 * portTICK_PERIOD_MS, right?

The calculation looks suspect.  For example,  #define configTICK_RATE_HZ (1),
#define portTICK_PERIOD_MS ((TickType_t) 1000 / 1) = 1000,
#define pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000) ((TickType_t)(((TickType_t)(1000) * (TickType_t)1) / (TickType_t) 1000U)) = 1.  Should the / in pdMS_TO_TICKS be a *.

@FiddlingBits to me they seem the same. Dividing for portTICK_PERIOD_MS means * configTICK_RATE_HZ / 1000 like pdMS_TO_TICKS states.

See this question on the esp32.com forum for a similar question

Using pd_MS_TO_TICKS is a bit cleaner coding style. It exposes a little less of the 'internal' details of FreeRTOS and helps avoid mistakes like accidentally doing portTICK_PERIOD_MS * x where the OP in a recent ESP32 forum question meant to use x / portTICK_PERIOD_MS.
